# Recommendations For Saving Files in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an ELB application that we have just added photo upload functionality to. Currently this saves the images in a folder within the deployment directory in ELB, saving the URL to a DynamoDb table. Everything works fine. Whenever a user wants to see an image we simply attach the URL to the src attribute of an  tag in the UI and the browser downloads the image directly.

However it occurred to me that if the underlying EC2 instance is terminated and re-started we will most likely lose all the photos. Am I correct in this assumption? If so, what's the best practice here? Should uploads always be saved in an S3 bucket? Any guidance hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should uploads always be saved in an S3 bucket?

**TL;DR**

In an elastic cloud environment, yes always move your static content to reliable external storage (in this case S3). It will make your app scale better. See the S3 question [here](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/faqs/#databases-storage.)

Resources:

- [IAM Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.html) Giving your app keys to access s3 right out of the box in Beanstalk.
- [S3 Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/GetStartedWithS3.html)
- [Media Reference Architecture](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_mediasharing_09.pdf) Describes at least part of what you're looking for. Look at the S3/Datastore/Web Server interaction there. More [here](http://aws.amazon.com/architecture/).

**Longer Description**

In a traditional architecture you might have a drive attached to a web server or two and you store the files there. You always expect those to be up. If you run out of disk space you have a problem. If you're server craps out, you've also got a problem. Even if you have a backup, you run the risk of both going down and you needing to restore all your data AND bringing up a server manually.

In a cloud architecture you're basically admitting that the "machine" is fallible and no longer relying on it to store any application state. It should be used to store things you need on disk to launch the app and/or temporary storage, but if you need something long term thats why services like S3 exist! By eliminating state from your app servers you can scale them automatically (however you see fit) without worrying about your users' content. If you had other services that needed that content, they could get it from there as well with the proper permissions.